Are these parameters possible?
I have an idea in mind to crrate a token/coin for a real world utility solving a problem in a huge sector. I want to create an SPL token/coin but it would need to be as safe and transparent as possible for the investors
1bil supply - no more minting possible thereafter
0.07% anti whale limit
0.02% transaction fee on all transactions
From all the tx fees collected 50% will be burned every month until total supply has been reduced to 600mil and I'd like that to happen publically so it can be seen in the blockchain.
The remaining 50% of tx fees collected will go on marketing, product development, community giveaways to holders of the token.
Founding team and angel investors keep 4.2% across 4 different wallets locked for 12 months
Basically I want to ceeate a coin the will revolutionise an industry but I need somebody to help me build it as I have no developer experience.


No minting is possible
Max token balance is not possible afaik using token or token22
trans fees is possible
burning fees is possible
token lockup is possible

I would suggest using the following tools and creating a whitepaper to recruit a developer onboard

streamflow.finance for lock / vesting
app.squads.so for multisig treasury
fluxbeam.xyz for token creation

For the max token balance you may need a custom program for that you need a rust / anchor developer
Read into Solana Token Extensions
token22

Hi thank you for replying I really appreciate it. I'm surprised that the max supply is not possible. If when the coin is created and there's only 1bil does the no minting facility prevent more coins coming into circulation?. If you could also like my question it would help me get to a score of 50 so I can start commenting on other posts. I'd really appreciate it and I will look at the resources you sent me. Regarding fluxbeam I've seen some videos on yt and they say that you can create a memecoin on fluxbeam with a transaction fee. I want to avoid snipes on the coin also when it first launches

Is fluxbeam safe? Because AFAIK after watching a yt vid you can have a transaction tax and anti whale mechanism on fulxbeam

Fluxbeam is safe.
The video is referring to Token22 aka Token Extensions.
Token22 allows the dev to create taxes amongst others things attached to the token.
This doesn’t make Fluxbeam unsafe - it makes developers more powerful but users need to learn how to understand what the extra features of the token are.
